How to get data from database and put it into a variable in AnyLogic
I imported an Excel file of 20 years of wind historical data (speed and direction) into Anylogic's database, and I created a Java code as per the photo below, in order to read each row of wind speed and direction simultaneously using ChatGPT and AnyLogic's help, now I created two variables to read and store the results (ReadWindSpeed) and (ReadingWindDirection). However, when I ran the model, I noticed a few things:

the event is running and reading the values of the database however all the results it shows are below (1) and there are no values in the table below (1)
the variables I created are reading only ONE value (as per the screenshot below), which is the last value in the file, but not reading anything else.

Anyone can help me what to do to extract the data into variables?
Reading Java Code
Screenshot of the model run
I tried to change it to dynamic variables and tried to import the wind speed alone into a table function, I looked at anylogic's help, asked chat gpt, watched videos on YouTube, with no luck
can you please tell me if my code is right? and what I can do about my problem?


the variables I created are reading only ONE value

Of course it does. You overwrite ReadWindSpeed and ReadWindDirection with every for-loop. So you only end up with the last value...
I suggest you first study the basics of (Java) coding and ALL the AnyLogic step-by-step tutorials (https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html) . Then, don't start with complex data. Try to load 1 data point and use it. Then several. Then all. Always test in between.
There are also good Java-for-AnyLogic tutorials out there.
ChatGPT is useful if you know coding. It will fool you if you don't :)

Actually, I'm not even a beginner in Java, I'm using the Anylgoic in my Master thesis, that's why I used ChatGPT to help me with the code, but apparently it's wrong, so can you please tell me how to fix it

don't overwrite but assign it to individual agents as you loop through them. There are 1 million ways to  solve this, depends on your actual model details. Suggest you create a simple dummy model with the same issue and open a new issue with just that 1 item :)

To show your code is not reading just the last line, amend your code as shown in the screenshot below;

